# How to aggregate some data in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [115,120,200], 'category': ['a','a', 'b'], 'clust': [1, 2, 3]})
```

I want to aggregate and count the amount of id of every category, which is in particular clust. For instance, result can also data frame where index row is clust and index column is category and values are amount of id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, let's use `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [115,120,200], 'category': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'clust': [1, 2, 3]})
df
```

Input Dataframe:

```
  category  clust   id
0        a      1  115
1        a      2  120
2        b      3  200
```

Group, aggegrate and reshape:

```
df_out = df.groupby(['clust','category'])['id'].count().unstack()
```

Output:

```
category    a    b
clust             
1         1.0  NaN
2         1.0  NaN
3         NaN  1.0
```